# Get my current address using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I was interested in getting my current address using Javascript and just figured this out by assembling some other SO threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951346/javascript-function-convert-geolocation-code-to-street-adress),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt)) so wanted to post this question and answer.

Please see answer below.

Comment: It gives me incorrect location but useful thing :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib sorry to hear its not working for you. I'm in the US and it gives me my exact address. Is the location it gives you even remotely close to where you live?

Comment: For me, it gives me a location 3 KM from where I am (On a desktop PC). Still, pretty nice for mobile devices, since they've got GPS for the coordinates.

Comment: @Cerbrus, yeah not too bad. Cool!

Comment: @AspiringAqib could be better, though glad the city and country are correct.

Comment: ahahhahha :P well, i never learnt google-maps scripting :( don't know about its working ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the HTML:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<p id='latitudeAndLongitude'></p>
<p id='address'></p>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var latitudeAndLongitude=document.getElementById("latitudeAndLongitude"),
location={
    latitude:'',
    longitude:''
};

if (navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else{
  latitudeAndLongitude.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showPosition(position){ 
    location.latitude=position.coords.latitude;
    location.longitude=position.coords.longitude;
    latitudeAndLongitude.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);

 if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng}, function (results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         console.log(results[0].formatted_address); 
         $('#address').html('Address:'+results[0].formatted_address);
       }
       else {
        $('#address').html('Geocoding failed: '+status);
        console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
       }
    }); //geocoder.geocode()
  }      
} //showPosition
```

Comment: If the user is using a device without GPS ,eg PC, the location is most likely to be the location of IP adress.In my case the location is 7 miles out.[HTML5 Documentation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface)

Comment: @davidstrachan thanks that is really good to know and appears to explain -@Cerbus's and -@Aspiring's comments above.

Comment: Great work @timpeterson it works very well. Just a little change to it... Using it as is, it redirects my browser on page load. So I removed the  ',location = { ... };' part of the code as location in Javascript redirect your browser. after this, it works super fine.

Answer (score 3):

use [HTML5 GeoLocation:](http://codeheaven.org/find-position-on-google-map-using-html5-geolocation-for-android-and-iphone.html)

```
function GetGeolocation() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetCoords, GetError);

}


function GetCoords(position){

  alert(position.coords.latitude);

  alert(position.coords.longitude);

  alert(position.coords.accuracy);

 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
      map.setZoom(11);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
      });
      infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});

}
```